# How to reject promise and handle/catch error in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, promise

I'm learning Angular2 and want to do a proper error handling of a method inside a service.

For testing purpose I changed the API, so that I get an invalid result for testing. I want to reject the Promise `("Received unexcepted data.")` and store the error message inside my angular-component.

My service method:

```
getBlocks(): Promise<Block[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            if (response.json() instanceof Array) {
                return response.json() as Block[];
            } else {
                Promise.reject('Received unexpected data.');
            }
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('An error occurred in MyService', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

the component where I call the service:

```
getBlocks(): void {
    this.myService.getBlocks().then(blocks => {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }, error => {
        console.log('fail callback');
        this.error = error;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('catch');
        this.error = e;
    });
}
```

I tried to implement the fail-callback of the promise, but my app keeps crashing with

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Received unexpected data.

So there is my error message, but it didn't get handled in my component correctly. How can I catch my Promise.reject() from the service correctly, so that I can store the error for example inside `this.error` variable.

Additional question:
I have implemented a success and fail callback of the then()-call. Is the catch() after that even necessary? Or should that only be done without a fail-callback? or are those two cases not comparable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to catch the error in your catch clause you just need to:

```
throw new Exception("received unexpected...");
```

instead of rejecting the promise.

[Promise.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) has docs for handling a reject. If this is what you want you should return the Promise.reject so whatever was expecting a promise can catch it.

Comment: but what's the purpose of promise.reject? shouldn't that be used in that scenario?

Comment: @JackO'neill Rejecting the promise wont catch it in your handler. Here is the docs for resolve. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

Comment: You can add a then() and handle it right there or pass back the Promise.reject() as it is a promise.

Answer (score 3):

Just change you code to return Promise.Reject

```
getBlocks(): Promise<Block[] | void> {
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            if (response.json() instanceof Array) {
                return response.json() as Block[];
            } else {
                return Promise.reject('Received unexpected data.'); // HERE
            }
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I got the following result:

> An error occurred in MyService Received unexpected data.
>
> fail callback

Comment: with `return Promise.reject('..');` I receive a compilation error `Argument of type '(response: Response) => Block[] | Promise<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => PromiseLike<never>'. Type 'Block[] | Promise<never>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<never>'.`

Comment: @JackO'neill, try changing method signature to ```getBlocks(): Promise<Block[] | void>```